# npm install receiving type error when using docker

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker, npm

I have pulled down the latest ubuntu docker image and I have installed node, npm, etc on the image. I am trying to do an `npm install` on my project. I keep receiving 3 errors like this. I will only show the first time it appears.

```
path.js:7
throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received { url: 'https://raw.github.com/imagemin/pngquant-bin/v0.3.5/vendor/linux/x64/pngquant',
name: 'pngquant',
os: 'linux',
arch: 'x64' }
at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
at Object.basename (path.js:1357:5)
at /MyProject/WebContent/node_modules/download/index.js:35:43
at each (/MyProject/WebContent/node_modules/download/node_modules/each-async/each-async.js:63:4)
at module.exports (/MyProject/WebContent/node_modules/download/index.js:33:5)
at /MyProject/WebContent/node_modules/bin-wrapper/index.js:108:20
at /MyProject/WebContent/node_modules/bin-wrapper/index.js:141:24
at /MyProject/WebContent/node_modules/bin-check/index.js:30:20
at /MyProject/WebContent/node_modules/executable/index.js:39:20
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:117:15)
```

So when I go to do a `gulp build` after my `npm install` the `gulp build` will fail. However, `npm install` "succeeds" even though I am getting these type errors.

One thing that is worth noting, I did add this config to my docker image: `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

A couple of more notes:

1. This works on my local machine mac or windows.
2. node -v v6.2.2
   npm -v 3.9.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Path must be a string.`

This is an issue with Node 6.

Downgraded to Node 4 and npm 2 and then `npm install` and `gulp build` will work.